# How do I display an array output in ul li

Tags: php

My current array

```
[attributes] => Array
    (
        [0] => Color, Black, 1
        [1] => Size, S, 0
    )
```

On `foreach` how to display this array to be something like this

```
<ul>
  <li class="alignleft">Color : Black</li>
  <li class="alignright">$ 1.00</li>
  <li class="alignleft">Size : S</li>
  <li class="alignright">$ 0.00</li>
</ul>
```

What I've done..

```
<ul>            
<?php
$c = true;
foreach ($_SESSION['checkout']['attributes'] as $key => $value) {
    echo '<li'.(($c=!$c)?' class="alignright"':' class="alignleft"').">$value</div>";
}
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think you need to rethink your array structure - something more like array('Color'=>'black', 'price'=>1)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as all your array entries look like that, this should work:

```
<ul>            
<?php
foreach ($_SESSION['checkout']['attributes'] as $key => $value) {
    $arr = explode(",", $value);
    echo '<li class="alignleft">' . $arr[0] . ' : ' . $arr[1] . '</li>';
    echo '<li class="alignright">$' . number_format($arr[2], 2) . '</li>';
}
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: This would work. Also, your answer from my post: [Arrays from multiple upload form, Upload images then insert to database (PHP, MySQL)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11195114/1399030) I would have marked correct if you didn't delete it. [**(Your comment)**](http://i4.photobucket.com/albums/y143/cute-spot/Animatiofgdn6.gif)

Comment: @Love Ha, well I didn't realize when posting the answer that someone posted a somewhat similar one 10 minutes prior.  I undeleted since you saw it worthy.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I prefer to use sprintf if I have to output a short html content. For easier readability of course.

```
<ul>
    <?php
    foreach ($_SESSION['checkout']['attributes'] as $key => $row) {
        list($label, $type, $price) = explode(", ", $row);
        echo sprintf('
        <li class="alignleft">%s : %s</li>
        <li class="alignright">$ %.2f </li>
        ', $label, $type, $price);
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is:

```
<ul>            
<?php
foreach ($_SESSION['checkout']['attributes'] as $key => $value) {
    $val = explode(', ', $value);
    echo '<li class="alignleft">'. $val[0]. ' : '. $val[1]. '</li>';
    echo '<li class="alignright">$ '. number_format($val[2], 2). '</li>';
}
?>
</ul>
```

A better way, however, would be if you could have more control over your array and use something like:

```
Array(

    [0] => Array(
        ['label'] => 'Color',
        ['value'] => 'Black',
        ['price'] => 1
    ),
    [1] => Array(
        ['label'] => 'Size',
        ['value'] => 'S',
        ['price'] => 0
    )
)
```

Then you wouldn't need to explode the $value and you could use `$value['label']` instead of `$val[0]` and `$value['value']` instead of `$val[1]`, etc...

Comment: Nice...almost the same answer.  But you'll want to concatenate your strings with periods, not commas.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is it faster to concatenate the strings before passing it as parameter(s) to echo, rather than just using the variable parameters feature in echo? [edit: faster, not fast]

Comment: I knew `echo` was a construct and forgot it could be used with commas since I rarely see it used that way. So your way worked as well. My bad.