# Arrays from multiple upload form, Upload images then insert to database (PHP, MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, forms, file-upload

Language: **PHP** / MySQL

I am going out of my mind, I really have to ask now... I have a multiple file upload form:

`<input type="file" name="fileupload[]" multiple>`

With the help of some Javascript, on each change made to this input, it appends a list of filenames, + a formatted string (grabbed from the filename) inside another input, so onchange we have a **layout as shown below** (assuming that we just added some images):

[image: Multiple Upload Form]
**Almost similar to:** http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/WWNnV/4/

---

**// An HTML representation of such layout would be...** (assuming that we added 3 images)

`<input type="file" name="fileupload[]" multiple>`

- image-name-1.jpg    `<input type="text" value="Image Name 1" name="keyword[]">`
- justsome_file.png    `<input type="text" value="Justsome File" name="keyword[]">`
- some_Img-031.gif    `<input type="text" value="Some Img 031" name="keyword[]">`

`<input type="submit" value="Upload">`

---

*I have it this way because aside from uploading the files, **I would also like to add them to my database, with a default title** based on its filename (and the option to set/change this title for each image as I upload it). There is no problem with my form.*

**PROBLEM:** My dilemma lies inside the PHP page where the form data/action is submitted.

I can only manage to either:

- Upload correct images, but get same title for all
- Insert correct titles, but get same image for all

**Here is my PHP action page:** (Currently uploading correct images, but having **same title** for all)

```php
<?php
// CONNECT TO DATABASE...
// INCLUDE UPLOAD CLASS LIBRARY
include (dirname(__FILE__).'/lib/class.upload.php');


$files = array();
foreach ($_FILES['fileupload'] as $k => $l)
{
    foreach ($l as $i => $v)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($i, $files))
        $files[$i] = array();
        $files[$i][$k] = $v;
        $imagename = $_POST['keyword'][$i];
    }
}

// create an array here to hold file names
$uploaded = array();
foreach ($files as $file)
 {
            $generate_name = rand(100,99999); 
            $generate_name_extra = rand(200,9999);
            $filenamex = "COVER_PHOTO_".$generate_name.$generate_name_extra."_".time();
            $filenamex_thumb = $filenamex."_thumb";

            $handle = new upload($file);
            if ($handle->uploaded) {
            $this_upload = array();

            ///// 1 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            $handle->file_new_name_body   = $filenamex_thumb;
            $handle->file_force_extension = true;
            $handle->image_resize         = true;
            $handle->image_x              = '300';
            $handle->image_ratio_y        = true;
            $handle->jpeg_quality = '100';

            // ABSOLUTE PATH BELOW
            $handle->process($absoRoot.'covers/thumbs/');
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            if ($handle->processed) {

      // store the image filename
    $this_upload['image'] = $handle->file_dst_name; // Destination file name
    $this_upload['body'] = $handle->file_dst_name_body; // Destination file name body
    $this_upload['extension'] = $handle->file_dst_name_ext; // Destination file extension

        $category_id = $_POST['cat'];
        $hiddenvalues = explode ("|",$_POST["cat"]);
        $category = $hiddenvalues[0];
        $category_name = $hiddenvalues[1];


                $sql = 'INSERT INTO cover (id, img, keyword, category_name, cat_id) VALUES ("", "'.$this_upload['image'].'", "'.$imagename.'", "'.$category_name.'", "'.$category.'")';
                 mysql_query($sql);
        }

    $handle->clean();
        header("Location: ./upload.php");
                $message = "";
    } else {

         echo '  file not uploaded to the wanted location';
         echo '  Error: ' . $handle->error . '';

      }
} ?>
```

(I use the [**Upload Class** by Colin Verot](http://www.verot.net/download/class.upload.php/class.upload.txt) to handle image uploads, and their FAQ tutorial to handle MULTIPLE image uploads on [this page, under: **What about multiple uploads?**](http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload_faq.htm?PHPSESSID=accbee5eb0a694348a445a61a4e40ba1))

**This would work perfect if I were just uploading images, however I added the functionality of adding each image data to my database. & This is where it gets confusing.**

I'm sure the key is placing the SQL query inside the right foreach, or perhaps making another one, but I've tried that & it only gives me 1 good result for either the image upload or the title, never for both.

I need to upload the image to the site, then store its data (including image path) to my database.

Please look into my code and enlighten me how to solve this problem? A snippet clue would really be great for now as I am already very confused after having tried all I could think of. Thank you so much!

Comment: Clean up the formatting for the block and update your post: `if (!array_key_exists($i, $files))`

Comment: I am quite uncertain how to do that, that block of code was from the Upload Class FAQ tutorial on [this page, under: **What about multiple uploads?**](http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload_faq.htm?PHPSESSID=accbee5eb0a694348a445a61a4e40ba1) I really don't see which is which from that block of code, but I have tried changing it before and the uploads stopped working so I just left it there. I, however, was the one who added the part: `$imagename = $_POST['keyword'][$i];`

Comment: **UPDATE:** I received the right answer from [**user:138383**, **Aaron W.**](http://stackoverflow.com/users/138383/aaron-w) His comment was one of the firsts, and the first one I tried that worked, but I couldn't mark it correct anymore because he deleted it. I have in some little way notified him of it, & I will wait in case he would like to resubmit it then I will mark his answer as correct. [**(His answer was...)**](http://i4.photobucket.com/albums/y143/cute-spot/Animatiofgdn6.gif) just to credit him. I almost died when it worked. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're gathering the file information you're overwriting `$imagename` on every loop so it will be assigned to the last one.  Try attaching it to the `$files` variable (hopefully this doesn't mess with the `upload` class you're using).

```
foreach ($l as $i => $v)
{
    if (!array_key_exists($i, $files))
    $files[$i] = array();
    $files[$i][$k] = $v;
    $files[$i]['imagename'] = $_POST['keyword'][$i];
}
```

Then update your `$sql` string to reference that

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO cover (id, img, keyword, category_name, cat_id) 
     VALUES ("", "'.$this_upload['image'].'", "'.$file['imagename'].'", 
         "'.$category_name.'", "'.$category.'")';
```

Answer (score 2):

You aren't saving your $imagename variable to the $files array, you're just resetting it each time.

```
    $files[$i][$k] = $v;
    $imagename = $_POST['keyword'][$i];
```

Should be something like:

```
    $files[$i][$k] = array($v, $_POST['keyword'][$i]);
    ...
    foreach ($files as $data) {
        list($file, $imagename) = $data;
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I do think one of your problems is your foreach:

```
$files = array();
foreach ($_FILES['fileupload'] as $k => $l)
{
    foreach ($l as $i => $v)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($i, $files))
        $files[$i] = array();
        $files[$i][$k] = $v;
        $imagename = $_POST['keyword'][$i];
    }
}
```

So you are going through each of the fields assigning their value to the right file which fits this structure policy:

```
_FILES => array(
    'name' => array(0 => 'file.txt'),
    'size' => array(0 => 235)
)
```

Which is correct for multifiles but then you do:

```
$imagename = $_POST['keyword'][$i];
```

Which does not look right. You are overwriting the var each time with the last looked at which means you will only ever get one input vlaue.